# How to change color of Vue 3 font awesome icon?

Tags: css, vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3

I'm using Vue version 3.2.1 and followed the official font awesome docs for **Vue 3** at https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome and also this video: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoDIpTuRWfM`

Embarrassingly, I can't seem to change the color for the icons, though I CAN change the background color (see up arrow in screenshot) and the opacity (see baby carriage in screenshot).

Here's my code:

**main.js**:

```
// BEGIN font awesome icons, per https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

import { FontAwesomeIcon, fontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'  // OPTIMIZE THIS LATER
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'  // OPTIMIZE THIS LATER
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'  // OPTIMIZE THIS LATER

import { dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
dom.watch() // This will kick of the initial replacement of i to svg tags and configure a MutationObserver


library.add(fas, fab, far)
```

// END font awesome icons

and **ReviewDetails.vue**, showing all the attempts I could think of:

```
<div>
    <div style="color:red">
    <fa icon="broom" size="lg"/>
    </div>
    <fa icon="star" size="lg" style="color: var(--warning)" /> &nbsp;
    <span style="color: var(--warning)"> <fa :icon="['fas', 'question']" fill="color:red" size="lg"/></span> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="arrow-up" size="lg" style="background:MistyRose" /> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="heart" style="color: var(--warning)" size="lg" /> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="bone" style="color:#E1FF00" size="lg"/> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="arrow-alt-circle-down" style="fill:#E1FF00" size="lg"/> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="bomb" fill="#E1FF00" size="lg"/> &nbsp;
    <fa icon="baby-carriage" size="lg" style="opacity: 0.2; color: rgb(222, 226, 230)"/> &nbsp;
    <fa :icon="['far', 'star']" size="lg"  style="color: #E1FF00" />
</div>
```

And here's a screenshot of what the code above yields:

[image: screenshot of attempts to change icon color]

Also, there's no local or global css that specifically addresses icons, [UPDATE] but inspecting in the browser shows the color is controlled by the following in **main.css** *(when I change `color: var(--primary);` below to `color: rgb(242, 114, 12);` for example, the color of the icons and most text changes)*:

```
/* variables */
:root {
  --primary: rgb(33, 37, 41); /* was #4f515a; */
  --secondary: rgb(28, 117, 188); /* was #ebebeb; */
  --warning: #da0f41;
}

 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
  color: var(--primary);
  line-height: 1.40; 
  font-size: 1.07rem; 
  }
```

UPDATE: I tested all solutions in Firefox, Safari and Chrome browsers and the problem is consistent.

Thanks!

Comment: Solution by @Joel is in the comments to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900556/1459653   Waiting for him to rewrite that answer or submit it as a new answer, in order to give him credit. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pure CSS then locate it, refer directly to the path and set the fill color.
Right click and inspect with console is the best way to locate elements, but for mor accurate try

```
<fa icon="bomb" color="#E1FF00" id="my_bomb_icon" size="lg"/>
```

and in the css (if inline color property don't work) add

```
#my_bomb_icon path {
    fill: #E1FF00
}
```

> Alternatively, you can try to add the color as a direct property, then you will create the icon like so
> `<fa color="red" icon="bomb"></fa>`. Also if you need a specific color then set the hex code `<fa color="#3caa0c" icon="bomb"></fa>`

Comment: Thank you Joel (and welcome to Stack Overflow!). I tried both of your suggestions and I'm afraid neither worked. Best, -M

Comment: Hi Mark, try to locate the icon's path and set the `fill` property to your color, also check if it's being overwritten by another property, in that case set the color as important, like so `.fa-heart path { fill: red !important; }`

Comment: Thanks Joel. I tried ```<fa icon="bomb" fill="#E1FF00 !important" size="lg"/>``` and that did not work either. I'm not quite sure how to "locate the icon's path" but I will figure that out tomorrow. Best, -M

Comment: Right click and inspect with console is the best way to locate elements, but for mor accurate try `<fa icon="bomb" color="#E1FF00" id="my_bomb_icon" size="lg"/>` and in the css (if inline color property don't work) add `#my_bomb_icon path { fill: #E1FF00 }`

Comment: Your last comment's suggestion worked! ```<fa icon="cloud" id="my_cloud_icon" size="lg"/>``` and in between ```<style>``` tags: ```#my_cloud_icon path { fill: #00d9ff }```  Please submit this as an actual answer, so I can give you full credit. Thanks!

Comment: Great notice! Hope your project be successful!

Comment: Please either change your answer or submit a new one, so you can get full credit.

Comment: Done! I let my first answer now as a comment because I already try and check again that is working, maybe to another one could works and help, but the solution for your case is as the main answer

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation says, you seem to have entered the style parameter incorrectly

Try this code:

```
<fa :style="{color: 'white'}" icon="heart"></fa>
```

Comment: Thank you @fanonano. I tried both ```<fa :style="{color: 'blue'}" icon="heart"></fa>``` and ```<fa :style="{color: 'blue'}" icon="heart" />``` and neither worked. Gratefully, -M

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me for both colors and other things like modifying animations: `<fa icon="fa-solid fa-flag-checkered" :style="{'--fa-animation-iteration-count': '1'}" shake></fa>`

Answer (score 0):

As you stated `color: var(--primary);` with `--primary: rgb(33, 37, 41);` set the color of your icon. I assume, that your own color get´s overwritten by this css attributes.

You can try to use [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) to archive, what you want. In your case you could try at your html:

```
<div id="main-div">
   <div class="wrapper-div" style="color:red">
      <fa class="red-icon" icon="broom" size="lg"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in your css you could scope like that:

```
#main-div .wrapper-div .red-icon {
   color: red;
}
```

If that doesn´t work, maybe because `class=""` isn´t rendered, just inspect in your browser to what element `<fa>` get´s rendered and scope it.

Comment: Thanks. Given: "The universal selector (*) has low specificity, while ID selectors are highly specific!" I wonder why it's not being overridden by the code as is. I'll try it and will report findings.

Comment: Thank you @Fabalance. Prior to trying your answer, I tried a solution in the comments to this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/68900556/1459653 Waiting for him to rewrite that answer or submit it as a new answer, in order to give him credit.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the solution. here you go. (vue3 :deep())

Template:

```
 <fa icon="xmark" size="2x" />
```

CSS:

```
:deep(.fa-xmark path) {
   color: red;
}
```